# How can I resolve this build warning involving a missing i386 architecture file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, frameworks, audiotoolbox

I am getting the following build warning:

```
ld: warning: in /Users/syalam/Documents/git/stocktwits-iphone/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox, missing required architecture i386 in file
```

How can I resolve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-imported AudioToolBox Framework, and it was all good.